# How to read data to an array without ''

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I was trying to read a data file to an array which include float and string.

`metadata = genfromtxt('iris_labels.tsv',delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
print(metadata)`

Which give me [image: output]

is that possible to ignore the ('') sign?

Comment: If you need to, use `int()` or `float()` to cast a string to a integer or float.

Comment: You mean you want to ignore single quotes?

Comment: @Nurzhan Yes, that what i mean.

Comment: There aren't any `'` signs in your data. They're added for the printing because you're putting the data in an array of strings.

Comment: @n.caillou But when i trying to write those array into a file, it does include the single quotes sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a numpy expert and I haven't tried it out but I think you're looking for something like

```
my_dtype=np.dtype([
    ('petal.w', np.float),
    ('petal.h', np.float),
    ('sepal.w', np.float),
    ('sepal.h', np.float),
    ('species', 'a32')
    ])
```

p.s. I don't know the actual order of your columns

Comment: what is this actually?

Comment: `genfromtxt` has a `dtype` parameter; a numpy dtype is a description of the structure of some data. If you're asking to load the data as strings, that's what you're going to get. You must find how to have the first columns converted to floats instead